# Post request triggering all if else statement and redirecting them

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am creating a login page as my first express project. when I am sending a post request with if/else statement, redirecting them based on input , it is executing all the if else statement and triggering message that header cant set after they are sent to client. After checking other answers, I found that it is running all if else request. So I removed the else statement. It worked fine, but I need a both if/else in order to direct user to pages if their credentials are incorrect.
Kindly help on what can I do to remove this error.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

var data=[{fname:"john",pass:"dawd123"},{fname:"red",pass:"qwerty"}];

var nameStore="";
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.render("login");
});

app.post("/",(req,res)=>{
  n1 = req.body.uname;
  n2 = req.body.password;
  for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i].fname===n1 && data[i].pass===n2){
      nameStore = data[i].fname;
      res.redirect("/home");
    }
    else{
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  }
});

app.get("/home",(req,res)=>{
  res.render("home",{name:nameStore});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is having a loop that sends responses. It is a bad idea. What you wanna achieve could be done in a cleaner way, like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

var data=[{fname:"john",pass:"dawd123"},{fname:"red",pass:"qwerty"}];

var nameStore="";
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.render("login");
});

app.post("/",(req,res)=>{
  n1 = req.body.uname;
  n2 = req.body.password;
  if(data.some(d=>d.fname === n1 && d.pass === n2)){
   return res.redirect("/home");
  }
  res.redirect("/");
 
});

app.get("/home",(req,res)=>{
  res.render("home",{name:nameStore});
```

Explanation about `some` method from MDN:

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns true if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function returns true; otherwise it returns false. It doesn't modify the array.

More details of what you are doing wrong:

> A router handler function should only return one response per request. In your case, if for example the user is not in the `data` array, you would end up with `data.length` number of `res.redirect("/");` per request.

Comment: Hey @yousoumar can you please explain this. data.some(d=>d.fname === n1 && d.pass === n2)).  what does d.some and d=> does.. ty

Comment: @Shekharlohach I added an explanation for that blow my answer. Take a look please.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolve your problem for letting know others that it has been answered.

Comment: Hey @yousoumar can you please tell what was I doing wrong. It would be really helpful and I can avoid it in future. Thnx

Comment: Wait a minute I am gonna add an explanation of what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Take a look at the end of my answer please. I added some explanation.